# Train Mask R-CNN Net for multiclass object detection with PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, mask-rcnn

I want to use the code given at this tutorial [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-mask-rcnn-net-for-object-detection-in-60-lines-of-code-9b6bbff292c3) and extend it to mulitclass-object detection.

Unfortunately, the tutorial does not explain how to do that.

What I want for a result is this picture: [here](https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:4800/format:webp/1*hIBM3fJk4AsE1KBDqREIFg.jpeg).

So, I guess, I somehow have to include the vessel class labels from the JSON-Files of the LabPics_V2 dataset into the training process, but how?

As I am quite new to PyTorch and python programming, I need some help for this task. If you have any ideas or suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That medium article has a link to the GitHub repo that includes all the code. I recommend maybe start with this:  https://learnopencv.com/pytorch-for-beginners-basics/   Then work your way to this: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html  Come back with very specific questions about those more basic tutorials.